# Cannot automatically add location for each and every page on my website

Tags: html, maps

i have created a website for hotel bookings. I have embedded a google map on every hotel's page. but the map shows the same location on every page. i want know how can i show the correct hotel location for different hotels on each page.
here is the html code

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Location:</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="map wow fadeInDown animated col-md-6" data-wow-delay=".5s">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d249950.6890172637!2d75.4064655!3d11.8016519!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3ba424110aea3ead%3A0x40dac77add54a87c!2sEdakkad%2C+Kerala!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1523005920045" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add HTML and JavaScript code so that we can help you

Comment: there is no javascript code. only html

Comment: Ok, i'll remove tag in that case. I'll answer the question know that I know that JS is not used

Comment: can you tell me how to add a map which shows location of the hotel customer chooses(i have choosen hotels in a small town)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in a parameter for GMaps in `[HERE]`

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Location:</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="map wow fadeInDown animated col-md-6" data-wow-delay=".5s">
        <iframe src="[HERE]" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

An example URL would be:
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&**parameters**

In the case you want to use location, you can use something like:
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=58.698017,-152.522067